# DataGridTextColumn only updating when scrolling out of row and back

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, datagridcolumn

So I have this weird problem,
I successfully binded a List to my DataGrid, and everything works as it should.
However, i have a ComboBoxColumn that i use to fill out some of the rows.

So for example, if ComboBoxColumn's selected item is "B" then the TextColumn should change to "Blld".
I achieved this by using a

```
DataGridPreparingCellForEditEventArgs
```

And a property get;set on my List with a

```
 PropertyChanged event
```

The DataGrid does update, however it will only show the new text "Blld" (the updated text) when i scroll down on my DataGrid (until you can't see the Row in question) and then back again.

What's going on?

Comment: Have you tried using Binding with Converter to a property in your ViewModel instead of firing some events?

Comment: Probabaly your change event is getting fired on scrolling datagrid.Mark breakpoint on property change of your property and check when  does it get fired.

Comment: Try `ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False"`. Let me know if this does not work.

Comment: Anatoliy Nikolaev: 
If I add ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False" to my DataGrid, it makes things worse, now if i scroll out of "sight" it won't update.

Comment: Farzi, my event gets fired whenever I change my selection in my ComboBox (as it's supposed to)
I'm not sure i understand what you mean

Comment: Could you show your code? Without it, I can not say for sure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For anyone else having this problem, i found out what was causing this weird thing.
I had an INotifyPropertyChanged event on the List i was binding to, but not the the type I was using.

You have to implement a PropertyChanged event to each of the values inside your List.